# Custom control property - Binding problem

Tags: wpf, binding

I have areally wierd problem when i'm using some simple custom control i've built:
this is the custom control code :

```
public partial class ToolButton : Button
{
    public string ToolID
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ToolIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolIDProperty, value); }
    }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolIDProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("ToolID", typeof(string), typeof(ToolButton), new    UIPropertyMetadata(""));


    public ToolButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now when i'm trying to ude this custom control in the main window like that :

```
<ItemsControl Margin="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <customControls:ToolButton Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Value.Name}"/> 
                                 </DataTemplate>
             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And the binding doesn't work !!

but when i'm using simple button the binding works excellent..

is someone faced similliar problem ??

Thanks...

Comment: This code is good, the problem lies elsewhere. Paste the code that's doing the binding.

Comment: see if this [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2008/04/22/wpf-custom-control-dependency-property-gotcha.aspx) helps.

Comment: Why is the class marked as `partial`? Is there the second part of the ToolButton class? If so, could you post that code also?

Comment: This is the default custom control template that vs2010 expose.there is no implemetation (my implementation) in the other part of the class

Comment: VS doesn't generate the second part (partial class) for Custom Controls. It does it for User Controls, though. And your control should be a Custom control. There shouldn't be any other parts. So just remove the .xaml part of the control and remove the `partial` keyword`.

Comment: Does your subclassed button work outside of the items control? - just drop in onto the form and see what happens. Sublassing standard controls in WPF is the last resort, it's highly advisable to use attached properties/behaviors as opposed to subclassing when you need to extend a standard control.

Comment: `InitializeComponent` should be also removed together with XAML

Answer (score 0):

put the following line into your ToolButton's constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: The only reason for a simple binding to fail (provided that the path is correct) is a missing Context.